# Get indexes of repeated values in array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to find indexes of repeated values in array.

E.g.

Input:

```
$data = @(1, 2, 3, 2, 1)
```

Output:

```
$indexes = @(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a different approach, you can use `try-catch` blocks with a hash table.

```
$data = @(1, 2, 3, 2, 1)
$hash = @{}
$indexes = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $data.count; $i++ ) {
    try {
        $hash.add($data[$i],$i)
    } 
    catch {
        $i
        continue
    }
}

# Output

$indexes
3
4
```

The idea here is to add each value as a key and the corresponding index as a value to the hash table. Since a `[hashtable]` object can only have unique keys, an exception will be thrown and caught. In the catch block, we just output the index which is ultimately stored in `$indexes`. The `continue` statement allows the loop to increment and keep processing.

---

Algorithmically speaking this solution is almost identical to the already proposed solution. However, it utilizes the more efficient `Add()` method of `[arraylist]` rather than rebuilding (`+=`) an `[array]` during each iteration. The performance is negligible in this example but could be worth considering in larger data sets. This also opts for the traditional `for` loop rather than `foreach`.

```
$uniqueValues = [collections.arraylist]@()

$indexes = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $data.count; $i++) {
    if ($uniqueValues -contains $data[$i]) {
        $i
    } 
    else {
        [void]$uniqueValues.Add($data[$i])
    }
}

# Output
$indexes
3
4
```

This solution maintains an `[arraylist]` of unique values (`$uniqueValues`). Any value that is not unique, its index (`$i`) is output and stored in `$indexes`. Uniqueness is determined by using the `-contains` operator to compare the current value in the `$data` iteration to what is already in `$uniqueValues`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a Hashtable for this:

```
$data = 1, 2, 3, 2, 1
$hash = @{}
$indexes = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $data.Count; $i++) {
    # the value you store in the $hash in the else block is not important
    if ($hash.ContainsKey($data[$i])) { $i } else {$hash[$data[$i]] = $true}
}
$indexes
```

Result:

> ```
> 3
> 4
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loop with `if` inside should do the job:

```bsh
$data = @(1, 2, 3, 2, 1)
$uniqueValues = @()
$duplicatesIndexes = @()
$data | ForEach-Object {$counter = 0}{
  if ($_ -notin $uniqueValues) {
    $uniqueValues += $_
  } else {
    $duplicatesIndexes += $counter
  }
  $counter++
}

# Output
PS> $duplicatesIndexes
3
4
```